# How to dynamically copy and maintain part of an Excel list to another workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm using Excel in Office 365.  I have a large list of data and need to regularly distribute portions of the list based on one column's criteria (division).  I'd like to maintain these portions in separate workbooks and not have to manually breakdown the list every time I need to distribute it.

Is there a way to do this so that adding a new row to one list automatically adds the same row of data to the other?  I don't mind if the master is the full list or the portions but I'm trying to avoid updating two lists as they're liable to get out of sync.

Comment: This could maybe be done with formulas. There not really much info to go on here. What have you tried so far?

Comment: All I know how to do is manual - filter/copy/paste.  I have previously used some VB to split the list onto separate worksheets, but again that's manual (ie. it happens when I press buttons).  Anything to do with formulas that I know can't account for any new rows being added which is the bit I'm asking for help on.  It may be that this kind of functionality doesn't exist and I *can* only do it manually but I don't know that is the case, hence asking here.

Comment: Based on the description, this could be done with formulas, this kind of functionality does indeed exist, no copy/pasting is required. This could also be done with Power Query but then you would need to click on the *Refresh All* button after adding rows to the master list. If you edit your question to provide some small sample tables that illustrate what you are working with (like in [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68669000/14148248)) or at least a screenshot to give a clear starting point, I am sure someone will provide a good answer.

Comment: You can use the new FILTER-Function to achieve what you want: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-function-f4f7cb66-82eb-4767-8f7c-4877ad80c759

Comment: That's the one Ike, thank you!!  I'm subscribed to a few YouTube channels and I thought I'd seen something relevant in a mailshot recently but couldn't remember what by whom but this is it.  So, so simple and dynamic.  Thank you so much.